# UI freezes while processing a list of tasks with a while loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, async-await

The application creates a collection of tasks to obtain folder info from a specific folder path.

This code performs well, but my issue is that the UI is freezing while adding tasks to the list, especially in the while loop, until all tasks are complete.

Here's the code:

```
Async Function ProcessFolders(ct As CancellationToken, FolderList As IEnumerable(Of 
String)) As Task
    ' Create a collection of tasks
    Dim processFoldersQuery As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of String())) =
        From folder In FolderList Select GetFolderInfo(folder, ct)

    Dim processQuery As List(Of Task(Of String())) = processFoldersQuery.ToList()

    ' Run through tasks
    While processQuery.Count > 0

        Dim finishedTask As Task(Of String()) = Await Task.WhenAny(processQuery)

        processQuery.Remove(finishedTask)

        Dim result = Await finishedTask

        folder_dt.Rows.Add(Nothing, result(0), result(1), result(2))
    End While
End Function

Async Function GetFolderInfo(folder As String, ct As CancellationToken) As Task(Of 
String())
    Return Await Task.Run(Async Function()
                              Dim folder_info = New DirectoryInfo(folder)
                              Dim result() As String = {folder_info.Name, Await 
                              GetFileMd5(folder, False), Await GetDirectorySize(folder)}

                              Return result
                          End Function)

End Function
```

How to achieve this without UI freezing? I have been looking into parallel and async loops and various different async techniques, but I am not sure how to implement them in this situation.

GetFileMd5() and GetDirectorySize() functions below:

```
Shared Async Function GetDirectorySize(path As String) As Task(Of Long)
    Return Await Task.Run(Function()
                              Return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(Function(t) (New FileInfo(t).Length))
                          End Function)
End Function

Private Async Function GetFileMd5(file_name As String, convert_file As Boolean) As Task(Of String)
    Return Await Task.Run(Function()
                              Dim byteHash() As Byte

                              Dim ByteArrayToString = Function(arrInput() As Byte)
                                                          Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder(arrInput.Length * 2)
                                                          For i As Integer = 0 To arrInput.Length - 1
                                                              sb.Append(arrInput(i).ToString("X2"))
                                                          Next
                                                          Return sb.ToString().ToLower
                                                      End Function

                              If convert_file Then
                                  byteHash = Md5CSP.ComputeHash(File.OpenRead(file_name))
                                  Return ByteArrayToString(byteHash)
                              End If

                              If convert_file = False Then byteHash = Md5CSP.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(file_name)) : Return ByteArrayToString(byteHash)

                              Return Nothing
                          End Function)
End Function
```

Comment: Remember that in order for `Async` to work, it has to be async all the way down.  You need to be starting with a top-level `Async Sub` event handler (they're not async by default) with which you `Await` your lower-level `Async` routines.

Comment: Also... if you want to get a sense of where it's freezing, try running under the debugger and breaking at a point where it's frozen, and see where you land.  That could give you a hint that will let you get more specific about what isn't working as expected.

Comment: @Craig I believe it is freezing somewhere in the While loop.

If there are, for example, 100 folders to get info from, it works within a second (with bride UI freeze. But if there are 10k folders, it freezes for a couple of seconds. So not sure how to use the debugger to find the freezing point.

Comment: Re "So not sure how to use the debugger to find the freezing point." - Presumably you have a test case that shows this behavior.  Run under the debugger, wait for it to freeze, when it does, hit break and see where it breaks.  You may need to use the threads or parallel stacks view to pick the right thread.  It's a sort of very coarse manual method of sampling-based profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of examples that may mitigate a form of lagging you're experiencing when the number of items in the list of folders you're processing increases.

In the current code, these two lines:

```
processQuery.Remove(finishedTask)
' [...]
folder_dt.Rows.Add(Nothing, result(0), result(1), result(2))
```

are executed in the UI Thread. In my view, the former is troublesome.
It's also not clear how the DataTable is used. It appears that when `ProcessFolders()` (which doesn't return that object) returns, a previously existing DataTable is blindly assigned to something.
`ProcessFolders()` shouldn't know about this, already existing, DataTable.

In the first example, the entry method (renamed `ProcessFoldersAsync()`), creates a DataTable that is meant to contain the data it generates and returns this DataTable.
You should pass the CancellationToken also to the `GetFileMd5()` and `GetDirectorySize()` methods.

```
Private cts As CancellationTokenSource = Nothing
Private folder_dt As DataTable = Nothing

Private Async Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SomeButton.Click
    Dim listOfFolders As New List(Of String) = [Some source of URIs]
    cts = New CancellationTokenSource
    Using cts
        ' Await resumes in the UI Thread
        folder_dt = Await ProcessFoldersAsync(listOfFolder, cts.Token)
        [Some Control].DataSource = folder_dt
    End Using
End Sub

Async Function ProcessFoldersAsync(folderList As IEnumerable(Of String), dtSchema As DataTable, token As CancellationToken) As Task(Of DataTable)
    Dim processQuery As New List(Of Task(Of Object()))
    For Each f In folderList
        processQuery.Add(GetFolderInfoAsync(f, token))
    Next

    If token.IsCancellationRequested Then Return Nothing
    Try
        ' Resumes on a ThreadPool Thread
        Await Task.WhenAll(processQuery).ConfigureAwait(False)

        ' Generate a new DataTable and fills it with the results of all Tasks            
        ' This code executes in a ThreadPool Thread
        Dim dt = CreateDataTable()
        For Each obj In processQuery
            If obj.Result IsNot Nothing Then dt.Rows.Add(obj.Result)
        Next
        Return dt
    Catch ex As TaskCanceledException
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Async Function GetFolderInfoAsync(folder As String, token As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Object())
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    Dim folderName = Path.GetFileName(folder)
    Return {Nothing, folderName, Await GetFileMd5(folder, False), Await GetDirectorySize(folder)}
End Function
```

---

In the second example, an `IProgress<T>` delegate is used perform the updates it receives from the `GetFolderInfoAsync()` method.
In this case, the DataTable already exists and could be already assigned to / used by Controls. In this case, the updates are performed in real time, as the async methods return their results, which may happen at different times.

This method may slow down the process, overall.

`ProcessFoldersAsync()` passes the Progress object delegate to `GetFolderInfoAsync()`, which calls `Report()` method with the data object it has elaborated.
The `UpdatedDataTable()` delegate method adds the new data arrived to the existing DataTable

Note that, in this case, if the Tasks are canceled, the updates already stored are retained (unless you decide otherwise, that is. You can always set the DataTable to `null` when you catch a `TaskCanceledException` exception)

```
' [...] 
Private objLock As New Object()
Private updater As IProgress(Of IEnumerable(Of Object))

Private Async Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SomeButton.Click
    Dim listOfFolders As New List(Of String) = [Some source of URIs]
    folder_dt = CreateDataTable()
    [Some Control].DataSource = folder_dt

    cts = New CancellationTokenSource
    Using cts
        updater = New Progress(Of IEnumerable(Of Object))(Sub(data) UpdatedDataTable(data))
        Try
            Await ProcessFoldersAsync(listOfFolder, updater, cts.Token)
        Catch ex As TaskCanceledException
            Debug.WriteLine("Tasks were canceled")
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub

Async Function ProcessFoldersAsync(folderList As IEnumerable(Of String), updater As IProgress(Of IEnumerable(Of Object)), token As CancellationToken) As Task
    Dim processQuery As New List(Of Task)
    For Each f In folderList
        processQuery.Add(GetFolderInfoAsync(f, updater, token))
    Next
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    Await Task.WhenAll(processQuery).ConfigureAwait(False)
End Function

Async Function GetFolderInfoAsync(folder As String, progress As IProgress(Of IEnumerable(Of Object)), token As CancellationToken) As Task
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    Dim folderName = Path.GetFileName(folder)
    Dim result As Object() = {Nothing, folderName, Await GetFileMd5(folder, False), Await GetDirectorySize(folder)}
    progress.Report(result)
End Function

Private Sub UpdatedDataTable(data As IEnumerable(Of Object))
    SyncLock objLock
        folder_dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray())
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function CreateDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim col As New DataColumn("IDX", GetType(Long)) With {
        .AutoIncrement = True,
        .AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
        .AutoIncrementStep = 1
    }
    dt.Columns.Add(col)
    dt.Columns.Add("FolderName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("MD5", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Size", GetType(Long))
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Although I managed to solve the issue with the help of your comments, your solution works perfectly and there's a lot to learn from it! I will mark your answer as a solution.